# Multiple silent installations in InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I wrote an installer using InnoSetup where user can make a multiple choice of which software they would like to download/install.

I am using a loop to install each software selected by the user **silently** like this

```pascal
ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + SoftwareName), '/VERYSILENT', '',
    SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
```

My question is concerning the second last parameter.

In my case where I am installing many silent installations, is there difference between using `ewNoWait` where each of them return immediately or using `ewWaitUntilTerminated` where they execute one after the other?

Which one would be more preferred, or safe, in my case?

Running many silent installations **at the same time** kind of worries me.

Comment: Btw, why don't you use `[Run]` section, instead of coding this manually?

Comment: Because all my software is downloaded first from remote location before I run ShellExec. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe [run] is used for executing executable files that is already packaged inside installer.

Comment: @Martin, no, you can run or open any file from `[Run]` section, not only those from the installer package.

Comment: @TLama Sure. But you cannot use `Run` to execute a file that you create/download from the `Code` section (except maybe for those with "post install" flag, what is not usable for OP's purpose).

Comment: @Martin, you can (it depends), but still, there is no mention when the OP downloads those files. I would expect before the installation. But well, I would personally prefer to install them as a prerequisite, before the installation, so the `[Run]` section would not be the best choice for me.

Comment: Well, true. (Almost) Everything is possible with InnoSetup.

Comment: I just found out this code returns immediately too even when I use ewWaitUntilTerminated
Exec(ExpandConstant('C:\Users\sweetPC\Desktop\RemoteLinkSetup.exe'), '/s /reboot=0','', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);

Comment: I found out why. The installer I am calling terminates itself then calls another installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some installers won't even run if another installation is running already.

So I would definitely use `ewWaitUntilTerminated`.